# Execute javascript function using jquery ajax that will change html, passing parameters at it and then execute another code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, parameters

i would like to make an Ajax request like that:

```
function test(par1,par2) {
    alert("add");
    return(par1+par2);
}

$.ajax({
      url: test,
      dataType: "script",
      data: 2,3,
      success: function(data) { 
            alert(data);
      }
});
```

I think that i am doing something wrong.

Comment: now my ajax is $.ajax({
      url: test(),
      dataType: "script",
      data: "par1=2&par2=3",
      success: function(data) { 
            alert(data);
      }
});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `test`, not reference it:

```
url: test("/mypath/", "somelocation.php")
```

The difference is in the brackets, and provided arguments. Without brackets you pass a function reference without executing it. This does not resolve to the executed value. With brackets you execute the function and pass to the `url` property the return value, which is what you want.

Of course, you need to decide what you pass to the function. In your case, you might have them in some variables.

Secondly, you need to change the value passed to `data` as well. It should be an object where each property corresponds to a parameter name:

```
data: {par1: 2, par2: 3}
```

jQuery will do the translation to the `url` format.

I have the impression your `test` function was intended to add parameters to the `url`, but since the `data` property is intended for that, you probably can do away with that function. Just assign the basic `url` to the `url` property, without parameters:

```
url: "/mypath/mypage.php"
```

Comment: I called that wrong too, now i wrote data:"par1=2&par2=3",